# System.Xml.Linq.XElement' does not contain a definition for 'XPathEvaluate

Tags: c#, xml, linq, razor

I'm trying to query an Xelement value passed in through model data and I'm getting the following error

```
var hello1 = (string)this.Model.hello.XPathEvaluate("/hello/helloworld]");
```

Namespaces in web.config:

```
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <add namespace="System.Xml.XPath"/>
</namespaces>
```

Comment: Are you referencing its assembly `System.Xml.Linq.dll`?

Comment: Or `System.Linq` ?

Comment: You are probably missing a reference to one of the assemblies mentioned in the previous comments or `using System.Xml.XPath` in your source file

Comment: It's an extension method, [`Extensions.XPathEvaluate Method (XNode, String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341675(v=vs.110).aspx) in the `System.Xml.XPath` namespace in the `System.Xml.Linq.dll` assembly.  Make sure you are `using` the correct namespace and referencing the correct dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the references from the config file and added it it directly to the page, @using System.Xml.Linq; @using System.Xml.XPath;